# PHP MVC query inside foreach loop

Tags: php, model-view-controller, foreach, controller

I am using mvc structure for a listing portal project. 
1. Listings are saved in table 'directory'
2. Categories saved in table 'categories'

I am trying to get category names foreach listings to pass it to view
my controller is like this

```
class Listings extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
       $lists = $this->model->getAllLists();
        require APP . 'view/_templates/header.php';
        require APP . 'view/listings/index.php';
        require APP . 'view/_templates/footer.php';
    }
}
```

My view looks like this

```
<?php foreach ($lists as $list) { 
echo $list->id;
echo $list->name;
echo $list->category_id;
//and so on...
?>
```

This will list all the lists saved in DB. Please help me how can I get categories name foreach `'category_id'`

Answer (score 0):

You should try with this

```
class Listings extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
     $data['lists'] = $this->model->getAllLists();
     $data['directory'] = $this->model->getAlldirectory();    
     $data['categories'] = $this->model->getAllcategories();    
     $this->load->view('header', $lists);
     $this->load->view('index', $lists);
     $this->load->view('footer', $lists);

  }
}
```

So now in view file .i.e index.php you can get all the data using like this:

```
<?php 
foreach ($lists as $list) { 
   echo $list->id;
   echo $list->name;
   echo $list->category_id;
  //and so on...
}

 foreach ($categories as $categories) { 
   echo $categories->category_id;
}
```

?>

Comment: Thanks! Will try this.